# remove all value of controller in flutter from memory with getx packages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-desktop

I'm working on flutter desktop application , where I need to delete all variables when move from page to another so I'm using getx packages,
so in the home page the app use about 138mb of memory

when I navigate to second page it use about 380mb of memory ,and when navigate back to home page it still using the same amount of memory although it shows in the console that the controller is deleted from memory.
I'm also using

```
Get.offNamed()
```

and

```
Get.delete<ControllerName>()
```

but that's not working

Comment: Is your `Get.put()` inside the `build()`?

Comment: yes it is inside the build() method of second page